# Connect local source code copy to a specific git repository branch

Tags: git

On my computer, I checked out the **develop** branch of our project (which has a **master** and a **develop** branch), by using:

```
git clone https://git.company.com/project.git -b develop
```

On a second computer, which had no access to the repository at a time, I copied the source code on a USB stick. Now I would like to check in my changes from the second computer.

What do I have to do to in order to connect to the **develop** branch of our repository? My guess would be:

```
git init
git remote add webapp https://git.company.com/project.git
git push develop
```

but since I'm using a GUI IDE (which is not available on the second computer), and I'm not very familiar with the git command line, I'm afraid I might mess up the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Have you copied the whole repository including the `.git` folder?**

Congratulations, you can use git commands on this folder as usual. I.e. make commits that you can later push to the remote repository. (Or just open the GUI pointing to the folder on the USB drive).

To find out, try to open the folder in (git) bash and run `git status`.

**If only files were copied and changed without the `.git` folder:**

Assuming you are checked out to the branch you want to update, just copy the changed files to the original repository, changes in working directory will appear.

**Flaws with your proposed approach:**

`git init` will create a new unrelated repository. Combining the two histories later is not a trivial task to do.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I go with your second approach, since I intentionally skipped the `.git` folder as I wasn't sure this is something that can or should be copied.